# insert a value in a input field using selenium and phpunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit

```
<table id="RegTable" class="GSTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 20px auto 0px; width: 450px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%">Email Address</td>
<td>
<input id="UserEmail" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="UserEmail" style="border: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

how can i insert a value in input field using selenium and phpunit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is not that precise but assuming you've already got selenium and phpunit installed and just want to know what methods to use I would do something like this:

```
$this->byId('UserEmail')->value('testmail@live.com');
```

That should insert the text "testmail@live.com" in to the input filed with the id "UserEmail".

Comment: It is 2 months later, but was wondering what framework/phpunit version/selenium server you are using? I get that the function doesn't exist and can't find any HELPFUL tutorials/documentation

Comment: I use the latest version of selenium and phpUnit so I guess that makes it selenium rc version = 2.33.0; and phpUnit = 3,8; The above code works for me, what error are you getting? is it saying that the value() function don't exist? Some documentation can be found here http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/index.html but very limited. this tutorial will help you get started aswell http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-selenium-2-with-phpunit/

Comment: I have phpunit 3.7, rc 2.33, but I think I am using the wrong "driver" class, my testcase class extends: `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` class. I get `Method byId not defined.` errors.

Comment: I think you should use the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase extension, and also update your phpunit it's rly easy if you installed it via pear.

Comment: I actually started using the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` extension and now I am getting a `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;` error, can I ask you maybe just to give me a code example?

Comment: do you have to chrome driver?, i think the default that comes with is firefox, so run the test with firefox, if that don't work i'll show a test code.

Comment: I got the chrome driver, just found out you have to do this: `$web_driver = new ChromeDriver("/var/selenium/chromedriver");`, I am struggling with the usage a lot since I can't find proper documentation... Also found out that phpunit 3.8 requires php 5.4 =<. So now I am upgrading php...

Comment: Okey, I never had to initiate the webdriver like that, only when I used java with selenium. this is how I initiate a test anyways, it's a login test . http://pastebin.com/kGrW0sk8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33547/discussion-between-we0-and-user1593846)